# Download from DropBox using DropBox.Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

anybody knows how to do this using DropBox.Api package and not DropNet package in C#?

```
//using DropNet:
 client = new DropNetClient("gwsdfs343sdfjtwt8", "6ygdfghdfhd34cf", userToken: "w5dgfdfg343", userSecret: "239dgfsgs34434o");
```

I've installed DropBox.Api but can't find any overload that takes these 4 parameters:

```
//using DropBox.Api
DropboxClient client = new DropboxClient("cU5M-a4ekhkhklhjb5h63563bh356k3kjkbjk356XH");
```

Which is the equivalent using DropBox.Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used the `generated token` from DropBox app, it wasn't possible to do it the other way, it was years ago, now it's easier using just the `generated token`